# Linearly accelerated charge experiment feasibility

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, qft-in-curved-spacetime

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_a_charge_in_a_gravitational_field#Proposal_of_Feynman) states:

> Though maybe it is surprising, there is no experiment that measures directly if an uniformly accelerated charge radiates in an inertial frame. Classic electromagnetic theory says it should, but this has never been confirmed by an experiment, because experiments use circular accelerating charges to verify the classic radiation equation, or use small particles like electrons that obey quantum laws (see again bremstrahlung)
>
> Feynman radiation equation yields the same value that classic equations in circular acceleration cases, but the big difference is that it yields no radiation for an uniformly accelerating charge seen from an inertial frame. Should Feynman be right, a charge uniformly accelerated in an inertial frame would not radiate in any frame.

Is this considered an open, untested question in physics, or is there other evidence to strongly convince us one way or another? To what degree do our current approaches to QFT in curved spacetime support or deny this? If it turned out that linearly accelerated charges did or didn't radiate in any frame, how would that impact our approaches at unification with gravity?

And on a different note, to what degree is an experiment to test this feasible e.g. placing a macroscale charged object in a large linear electric field such as those used for x-rays? (If this should be a separate question let me know.)

Comment: If nobody has done any experiments, then it's an open and untested question by definition. I am not sure one would expect a whole lot of surprises from a test, though. Why, exactly, should uniform acceleration be different from any other form of acceleration?

Comment: Wikipedia explains that, depending on how self-interaction is treated, a uniform acceleration can behave significantly differently than nonuniform acceleration. (With self-interaction, uniform acceleration does not cause radiation; without self-interaction, it does radiate.) Although I guess it is technically an "open question", I'm wondering to what degree it's regarded as actually unknown. For instance, gravitational waves were no longer "open" long before detection due to other phenomena that were connected to the same theory (precession / redshift / gravitomagnetism..)

Comment: Self-interaction has never been observed, so why should it suddenly pop up in uniform acceleration? The need for gravitational wave cosmology doesn't stem from the question whether gravitational waves exist or not, it stems from the question about the statistics and detailed behavior of strongly gravitating merging binary systems. I don't think you would have found a substantial number of physicists who would have bet on the non-existence of gravitational waves, but you also wouldn't have found anybody who could have told you much about merging compact binaries.

Comment: I didn't know that self-interaction was unobserved. In the past I had read articles such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force that seemed to imply it was a likely, if not established, phenomenon?

Comment: That's momentum conservation. Why does one need self-interaction for that?

Comment: I understand that under a quantum picture with photons, the particle is emitting photons preferentially in one direction, and when it emits one, it experiences a change in momentum backwards. (My QFT is very limited, forgive me if I'm wrong.) But from a classical standpoint, where is the force coming from? If not from the particle's only electric field contributions acting on itself, which I would call self-interaction.

Comment: Photons are not particles. Neither are particles that obey quantum mechanics particles. They are all quanta. Of course any semi-classical calculation that tries to pretend that quanta are classical particles will encounter fundamental problems, but they are home-made. Garbage-in-garbage-out. From a classical point of view forces are simply momentum conservation expressed in slightly different terms. In a relativistic quantum field theory talking about forces doesn't make any sense, but momenta and their conservation is still well defined.

Comment: The distinction between quanta/particles here doesn't seem relevant to most of my question, unless I'm missing something big. I'm asking in particular about the applicability of a "a semi-classical calculation that pretends [particles are classical]", and its plausibility and compatibility with quantum theory; so dismissing that as "garbage-in" doesn't help me understand. This also leaves me still curious about feasibilty of experiment, in case anyone has useful information on that.

Comment: You are the one who went from a perfectly classical electrodynamics question to gravity and quantum mechanics, I had nothing to do with that. I simply asked why one would expect linear acceleration to be special. That question has not been answered. In electrical engineering there is certainly absolutely no difference between the two and we are pushing a heck of a lot of charge around every day both in circular and linear fashion.

Comment: Some relevant discussion https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-does-an-accelerating-charge-radiate-solved-or-unsolved.65767/page-2. There's mentioning of x ray emission from synchrontrons as confirming that charges radiate in accelerating frames, and there's so some mentioning of Lienard wiechart potentials on how there is no radiation only in th coaccelerating frame. But otherwise I am not sure if the synchrontrons and free electron laser mentioned that are already demonstrations of the experiment you are seeking

Comment: @Secret: I think the OP makes the point that nobody has done an experiment with macroscopic charges. I fully believe that, since the total radiated power would be very small. Is that an experimental hole in the theory? Yes, I believe so. Can we live with that? I can since it has no consequences. If it had consequences, we could do the experiment, after all. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Secret! :) Certainly the person talking in that thread seems less-than-trustworthy ("photons can't go at the speed of light due to their mass!"), but it sounds like there are likely reports from SLAC on observations of electrons radiating. Just to make sure I understand, that would be good evidence that Feynman's proposal was incorrect, yes? What's the difference between the "self-interaction" he suggests and the "self-force" of Abraham-Lorentz, where the former is wrong and the latter is correct?