# Shooting an electrically neutral ball vs. a charged ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, electromagnetic-induction

If we had two identical conductive spheres of masses $m$, one with $–q$ charge and one neutral, would it take the same amount of energy to accelerate each of them to a certain velocity $v$?

Uncharged sphere would require the energy $\frac{mv^2}2$.

In the charged sphere case, wouldn’t the acceleration of the surplus electrons produce a net and increasing magnetic field which would cause an impeding electric field (impeding in the direction of the acceleration) on these electrons? Wouldn’t the sphere of electrons show an inductive reaction, counter-acting on the force we are applying to the sphere, requiring us to give more energy to push it up to the velocity $v$ than the neutral sphere would?

If so, could we say that this extra energy (given to overcome the impedance) would then be stored in/as the magnetic potential of the charged object?

Are there any considerations like this or any similar effects, that are commonly made in designing particle accelerators?

Could such an "inductive-flywheel" be thought to have an increased "potential energy stored/flywheel mass" ratio than a purely mechanical frictionless-flywheel for energy storage?

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, the answer to this question may depend on the precise nature of the acceleration.

In general, if the acceleration varies in strength and/or direction, the accelerated charge will radiate and it takes more energy than the final kinetic energy to reach the desired velocity.

However, the somewhat theoretical case of a purely constant acceleration, constant in strength and direction, has so far not been decided by experiment.  Feynman, the Nobel laureate, argued that the radiative power would be proportional to $\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot\frac{d^3x}{dt^3}$.  For a constant $a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ this is zero. Hence, a charge under constant, linear acceleration would not radiate.

Have a look at [Linearly accelerated charge experiment feasibility](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270343/linearly-accelerated-charge-experiment-feasibility)

A rotating flywheel of charged objects, however, would unequivocally be radiating energy off into space.  So that's not what you would want from an energy-storing flywheel.